# CakePHP - HABTM relationship and find()

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

this is my situation, I have a Post model that can belong to multiple Categories. This I figured out how to do:

```
class Post extends AppModel
{
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Category');
}
```

And the Category model:

```
class Category extends AppModel
{
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array ('Post');
}
```

Now, this all works fine and all that. But I just cannot figure out how to search for posts that belong to a certain category, for example "News" with the id of 1 to use in:

```
class CategoriesController extends AppController {
    function view ($id = 0) {
        // doesnt work
        $this->Category->Video->find ('all', array('conditions' => array('category_id' => $id));
    }
}
```

I've been trying to find an answer on Google and the CookBook but have found nothing yet. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing a find on Video model, when you showed association on Category and Post models, not Video. Assuming this is a typo error:

If you want to search, as you stated, posts that are of "News" category do in posts_controller.php:

```
$this->Post->Category->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Category.name'=>'News')) );
```

Or in the categories_controller.php

```
$this->Category->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Category.name'=>'News')) );
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but with one problem: the Post model belongsTo a User. But in the list I get from your method, there is no associated username and User data provided. Is this intended to work like this or is it obtainable some other way? Otherwise, great answer, fast, too. :)

Comment: Add 'recursive' => 2 in the param array of the find method it should be enough

Comment: Works :) One more thing though, say a user browses through a category. Now, he wants to have the news in that category sorted by date ASC. Can this be done in the categories controller or will I have to do it in the news controller?

Comment: Try to add 'order' => array('Post.date ASC') in the param array too. I'd be more categoric if I would see your current code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following which should work:

```
$this->Category->bindModel(array(
        'hasOne' => array(
            'CategoriesVideo'
        ),
    ));
    return $this->Video->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'CategoriesVideo.category_id' => $id,
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

EDIT: Sorry, was looking at the wrong code.  This should work.

Comment: That won't work.  You can't query against a HABTM relationship like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest bet would be to search the Category itself, and allow the [recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1063/recursive) level to also return associated Posts (or Videos, or whatever you're doing):

```
//in the category controller
$this->Category->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Category.id'=>$id));
```

There are many options for searching against HABTM data, but the above is the easiest.

Here's the page in the CakePHP book that describes different ways to query against a HABTM relationship:

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM